# Storing results of loop iterations in R

Tags: r, loops, iteration, storing-information

I am trying to store the results of the  the code below, however I could only come up with a solution to save the results of the model with the smallest sum of squared residuals. This was useful until the results were in the limits of the range of both c and gamma, therefore I need to assess the characteristics of other points. For this I need to store the results of every iteration. Does anyone know how to do this in this case?

Thanks in advance!

```
dlpib1 <- info$dlpib1
scale <- sqrt(var(dlpib1))
RSS.m <- 10

for (c in seq(-0.03,0.05,0.001)){
  for (gamma in seq(1,100,0.2))
    {
    trans <- (1+exp(-(gamma/scale)*(dlpib1-c)))^-1
    grid.regre <-lm(dlpib ~ dlpib1 + dlpib8 + trans + trans*dlpib1 + 
                  + I(trans*dlpib4) ,data=info) 
coef <- grid.regre$coefficients
RSS <- sum(grid.regre$residuals^2)

if (RSS < RSS.m){
  RSS.m <- RSS
  gamma.m <- gamma
  c.m <- c
  coef.m <- coef
  }
 }
}
grid <- c(RSS=RSS.m,gamma=gamma.m,c=c.m,coef.m)
grid`
```

Comment: as a general tip, avoid using `c` as a variable name in `R` since it is also the name of one of the most highly used functions, `c( )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably avoid the `for` loop altogether.  However, as for how to accomplish your task,  you simply need to index whatever object you are storing the value in.  For example,

```
# outside the for loop
trans <- list()

# inside the for loop
trans[[paste(gamma, c, sep="_")]] <- ...
```

Comment: Hello Ricardo. Sorry to ask this after so long, but I'm writing a package that uses this function, and it takes to long for it to complete the loop when I include more parameters like c. I noticed that you said I could avoid looping for the result. Can you tell me how you think this can be done? Thanks a lot!

Comment: hi Javier, it's best to open a new question for this and link bank to this one

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way to store model results by iterations is in a `list`:

```
List = list()
for(i in 1:100)
    {
       LM = lm(rnorm(10)~rnorm(10))
       List[[length(List)+1]] = LM
     }
```

Comment: Thank you all. I went with Roxxy.32's solution. Here is the final code

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure to save all iterations of the RSS's you could do something like this:

```
dlpib1 <- info$dlpib1
    scale <- sqrt(var(dlpib1))
    RSS.m <- rep(0,N)
    coef <- rep(0,N)
    i <- 0

    for (c in seq(-0.03,0.05,0.001)){
      for (gamma in seq(1,100,0.2))
        {
        trans <- (1+exp(-(gamma/scale)*(dlpib1-c)))^-1
        grid.regre <-lm(dlpib ~ dlpib1 + dlpib8 + trans + trans*dlpib1 + 
                      + I(trans*dlpib4) ,data=info) 
    coef <- grid.regre$coefficients
    RSS.m[i] <- sum(grid.regre$residuals^2)
    i=i+1


      }
     }
    }
```