# storing output vector from r loop which optimizes a function

Tags: r

I wrote a function with two variables in which which I want to optimize Z:

```
fr<-function(Z) {
delta<-pnorm((Matrix81fulld$CumZavg-sqrt(rho)*Z)/sqrt(1-rho)) - pnorm((Matrix81fulld$CumZavgLow-sqrt(rho)*Z)/sqrt(1-rho))

sum((Matrix81fulld$n*(Matrix81fulld$Prob1981 - delta)^2)/((delta*(1-delta))))
}
```

The above function works. I pass a value of rho and then solve for Z. I wrote a loop which passes multiple values of rho to the fr function to optimize Z across different values of rho:

```
for (rho in c(0.01, 0.025, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.3)){
     o=optimize(fr,interval=c(-2,2))
     n=nlm(fr,p=0)
}
```

Of course, when I print 'o', only the optimized value for rho=0.3 is returned because all the others are overwritten. I would like to store both o and n in 2 separate vectors which contain the results across values of rho. I know similar questions have been asked but they all seem much easier as the loop is generally run for i in 1:10, for example. In this case I have 7 specific values of rho I interchanging and then optimizing fr in each case..not sure if I am just pretending this is more complicated or if it really is, but I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: Is this not as simple as `res <- lapply(c(0.01, 0.025, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.3), function(rho){ c(o=optimize(fr,interval=c(-2,2)), n=nlm(fr,p=0)) })` ?

Comment: unfortunately, my question could have been worded better. Rho is not a variable in a dataset; it is only defined as a term in the mathematical expression under function the 'fr' . So when you create function(rho), it has no values and r returns an error 'object "rho" not found'.....when I solve this by hand I must define rho = 0.01; rho=0.025, for each time I optimize. This is why I had tried the loop approach--mostly to consolidate my code and remove the potential for error. I can print the values within the function to confirm it is working...I just haven't figured out how to store them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that all you need is to store the values in each loop iteration

```
o = list()
n = list()
i = 1
for (rho in c(0.01, 0.025, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.3)){
  o[i]=optimize(fr,interval=c(-2,2))
  n[i]=nlm(fr,p=0)
  i=i+1
}
```

Alternatively (answering your comment):

```
o = list()
n = list()
all_rhos = c(0.01, 0.025, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.3)

for (i in 1:7)){
  rho = all_rhos[i]
  o[i]=optimize(fr,interval=c(-2,2))
  n[i]=nlm(fr,p=0)
}
```

Comment: yes this works, thanks. And this solution can be derived from another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19057628/storing-results-of-loop-iterations-in-r             (I was looking at it while you responded)....your solution is helpful. One more question for full understanding: Why is the i = i + 1 needed? I am thinking because in the second iteration this will give us o[2], n[2], and in the third it will give o[3], n[3]...etc?

Comment: i = i + 1 is needed because you're not looping on i, you're looping on rho. I edited my answer to point that out.

Comment: thanks-the edit is helpful. The 'i' needing 'i+1' piece was what kept messing me up when i tried it on my own but your example shows how I actually could have done it either way...so easy now that I see it in front of me