# How do I put the output of a nested for loop into a vector in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, vector

I am a new R programmer, and I am trying to randomly generate p*q random numbers. I have the following code:

```
 for (i in 1:p){     
   for (j in 1:q){       
     X_ij <- rnorm( 1, mu , 1)       
     print(X_ij)     
   }   
}
```

let p=2 and q=3 as an example, this code will print 6 values. How do I put these into a vector?

I tried to do something like the following:

```
for (i in 1:p){ 
    for (j in 1:q){
     X_ij <- rnorm( 1, mu , 1)
     x_ij_vector <- c(X_ij, X_ij)
    }
}
```

I thought this might create a vector of X_ijs, but it did not.

Comment: You don't need a loop, `x <- rnorm(p * q, mu, 1)` is sufficient.

Comment: @Ritchie Sacramento is correct. But that may not answer your question if you need to store a loop output in the future. to do so, you need to store the results of any loop into a global variable. you can either do so by binding result (rbind, cbind) by result to an external vector or you can iteratively overwrite a prepared data frame/matrix/list/... outside your function. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19057628/storing-results-of-loop-iterations-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize a vector `v` and a running index `u` and fill it iteratively.

```
v <- numeric(p*q)
u <- 0
set.seed(42)  ## for sake of reproducibility

for (j in 1:q) { 
  for (i in 1:p) {
    u <- u + 1
    v[u] <- rnorm(1, mu, 1)
  }
}

v
# [1]  1.3709584 -0.5646982  0.3631284  0.6328626  0.4042683 -0.1061245
```

A `while` or a `repeat` loop might be better suited here, though.

```
v <- numeric(p*q)
u <- 0
set.seed(42)

repeat {
  u <- u + 1
  v[u] <- rnorm(1, mu, 1)
  if (u == p*q) break
}

v
# [1]  1.3709584 -0.5646982  0.3631284  0.6328626  0.4042683 -0.1061245
```

Maybe you wanted a matrix?

```
X <- matrix(NA_real_, p, q)  ## initialize empty matrix

p <- 2; q <- 3; mu <- 0
set.seed(42)

for (j in 1:q) { 
  for (i in 1:p) {
    X[i, j] <- rnorm(1, mu, 1)
  }
}

X
#            [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
# [1,]  1.3709584 0.3631284  0.4042683
# [2,] -0.5646982 0.6328626 -0.1061245
```

Note, that matrices generally should be filled column by column.

However, as also stated in comments, for the sole generation of random vectors/matrices in R no loops are needed:

```
set.seed(42)
rnorm(p*q, mu, 1)
# [1]  1.3709584 -0.5646982  0.3631284  0.6328626  0.4042683 -0.1061245

set.seed(42)
matrix(rnorm(p*q, mu, 1), p, q)
#            [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
# [1,]  1.3709584 0.3631284  0.4042683
# [2,] -0.5646982 0.6328626 -0.1061245
```